# Pandas - Filter rows where columns match atleast once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below:

```
Name ID1    ID2
Joe  248    248
Joe  248    326
Joe  721    248
Anna 295    295
Bob  721    248
Bob  721    326
Bob  248    566
```

I need to keep only the rows that do not have matching ID1 & ID2,
with the exception that, if both the IDs matched at least once for a Name, then drop them.

For example:

For Name = Joe, IDs match once (248), so **remove all rows with Joe**.

For Name = Bob, IDs never match, so **keep all rows with Bob**.

So far, I've tried:

Dropping duplicates by sorting names and checking if IDs match or not. But this does not take into account IDs matching at least once.

```
df  = df.sort_values(['Name']).drop_duplicates(['Name'],keep='first')
```

Not sure if pandas can drop duplicates with condition where something matches 'atleast once'.

Comment: In your question, you say "if both the IDs matched at least once for a Name, then drop them" - do you mean drop all rows with _that Name_?  Whether they match or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can calculate the names to remove and then use Boolean indexing:

```
names_to_remove = df.loc[df['ID1'] == df['ID2'], 'Name'].values

res = df[~df['Name'].isin(names_to_remove)]

print(res)

  Name  ID1  ID2
4  Bob  721  248
5  Bob  721  326
6  Bob  248  566
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda grp: grp if not (grp['ID1'] == grp['ID2']).any() else None).dropna()
```

Explanation: Groupby Name, then if there is any index for which ID1 and Id2 do NOT match, return the group. Else, return None and then drop the null columns.